# http:// website not loading for old users

Tags: http, caching, https

I recently moved a website from https://www.ezacu.com to http://www.ezacu.com and I'm finding that the website loads for people who have never visited the https version, but not for people that have.

I believe that this is either because their browsers keep autocorrecting http to https (since it used to be https) or because their browser is trying to use a cached version. Im not sure how to find out or how to fix the issue, but it is especially difficult for me because it works on my computer/phone; The issue is with other users.

I am hosting the website on amazon S3

Comment: Just curious to know. Why the downgrade from https to http?

Comment: I want to be able to use an amazon EC2 server as my backend, which was more difficult when I was using https

Comment: Did you ever have redirects from http to https for your website? If true, then some browsers (Google Chrome) will remember the previous redirect. Note: the trend today is to stop using HTTP and start pushing users to HTTPS. Google is one of the leaders on this. https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/xygdxq/google-will-soon-shame-all-websites-that-are-unencrypted-chrome-https

Comment: @JohnHanley The problem was I switched to S3 because it ended up being a lot easier to cofigure

Comment: S3 supports HTTPS.

Comment: @JohnHanley not with your own domain name.  That requires CloudFront in front of S3.

Comment: @Michael, good point. I missed the hosting on S3 part.

Comment: So Apparently everyone's browser is autocorrecting to https, which is something I can't easily overcome, right?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to create a CloudFront distribution with your domain name as its Alternate Domain Name, attach a free SSL cert from Amazon Certificate Manager, type the web site hosting endpoint from your bucket as the Origin Domain Name (don't select the bucket from the drop-down list -- that won't enable the web site hosting features of S3), then point your DNS to CloudFront.

When you use CloudFront with S3, you pay bandwidth charges to CloudFront instead of to S3, so the cost difference is negligible and in certain cases, bandwidth can actually cost slightly less.

There isn't a way to convince browsers not to try to use HTTPS once they believe it's available.